# Matlab Bayesian Network toolbox and continuous values

Tags: bayesian, matlab, bayesian-network

I have two doubt, one about  theory and one about practical problem.

**First i have not full understand** how to work a bayesian network with continuous values. 
I have learn that i can approximate P(A) (the probability of node A) with a Gaussian Distribution. But i have a dataset, mean and variance of the Gaussian Distribution is the  mean and the variance of the dataset ?

And if i have P(A|B,C), with A and B with continuous values, how i can represent with a Gaussian Distribution?

**The practical problem** is i need to learn a a Bayesian Structure from a continuous values Dataset and i use this toolbox for matlab:
http://code.google.com/p/bnt/
(Bayes Net Toolbox for Matlab by Kevin Murphy)

Now how i can use to learn a Bayesian Structure from a Dataset (of continuous values) with this tools?

If i use **learn_struct_K2** function i need the order of nodes but where i can get this order? There are other useful functions in this toolbox that you know? (About this problem)

Comment: I have a similar problem, did you find a way to do it? I would appreciate some advice. Cheers.

Comment: @Neptune, General answer to this is: toolboxes and modules for structure learning, parameter learning, and inference for BN's with continuous nodes is a very under-developed topic. The vast majority of BN applications discretise their continuous values.

Comment: and I'm go to discretise too.

Answer (score 1):

I guess its late for answering the question. nevertheless I will still leave my answer so that the future viewers can seek help from it.

**1)** Bayesian Networks are designed to reason about static process. and the observations has to be discretised (in case of continuous Node variables.) It is to be noted that it is a best practice that the continuous nodes are discritised in regular intervals. Also, if you want to work with continuous nodes you can check the concept introduced in this [paper](http://ai.stanford.edu/~nodelman/papers/ctbn.pdf). This helps in both continuous variable and Temporal dimension problem.

**2)** To get Node ordering for method "learn_struct_K2" you can use either of the following methods.

- Based on dataset, you can for the node ordering using Hierarchy, domain Knowledge and Previous literature work (e.g. For a Bayesian Network with disease progression one can easily attain some hierarchy of node from literature or expert practitioner)
- For unsupervised Node ordering based on data methods like sampling **Gibbs Sampling**, Greedy Tree structure learning methods can be used. and based on the tree structure a topological sorting can give you a proper node ordering.

Hope this helps!